# Do parameters sent to a JavaScript module constructor require special handling?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript module that looks like this:

```
var TestModule = function(param) {

  this.display = function() {
    console.log(`testModule.display called, with parameter: ${param}`);
  }

}
module.exports = TestModule;
```

I also have a program that uses this module, like so:

```
var TestModule = require('./test-module.js');
var testModule = new TestModule('asdf');

testModule.display();
```

When I run the program, I get the following output:

```
testModule.display called, with parameter: asdf
```

All of this seems to be fine so far, and doing what I want: making the value I send in available to functions within the module.

However, I have also seen the following done in module code:

```
var TestModule = function(param) {
this.param = param;

  this.display = function() {
    console.log(`testModule.display called, with parameter: ${this.param}`);
  }

}
module.exports = TestModule;
```

Running this second version gives me the same output as the first.

My question is, what is the purpose of `this.param = param`?  What does that do for me that my original version does not?

Comment: Usually you would define `display` on `TestModule.prototype`, so that you don't end up creating multiple function objects for each instance that do the same thing. When it's defined on the prototype, you don't have access to the `param` variable from the surrounding scope, so `this.param` is needed

Comment: You’re essentially asking what the difference between variables and properties is. See [What is the difference between javascript property and javascript variable?](/q/26421417/4642212).

Comment: JS supports actual classes now, I recommend learning that instead of using functions as classes.

Comment: @ChrisG It's still recommended to learn that classes are functions with a `.prototype` property, no matter what syntax is used to create them.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that the object returned by the constructor has the property attached to its prototype.

In the second version, `console.log(testModule.param)` gives `"asdf"` and the first version gives this property as `undefined`.

If you attach functions to the prototype, which is the normal approach because it only defines each function once, these functions' closures won't see `param` if it's not been attached to `this` as the second version does.

The `module.exports` has no bearing on this, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.param = param
```

Will store the argument on the object itself, allowing you to do `testModule.param` and access it (like how you do `testModule.display()` to access the `display` method)

Additionally, you should use the [ES6 Class Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) to modernise your code